# Improve motivation in highly pessimistic team as new senior dev

Tags: new-job, motivation

I'm a new hire in a software development team. My existing peers, with less than a year there, are extremely pessimistic.

As the dev with the highest level in the team I guess improving morale is expected from me, but I would rather be writing code.

The team is split in several geos. My local geo is the newest.
Also, I'm concerned that, as a cross-geography team, management could end biased against people in our geo, affecting opportunities for all of us.

Peers are pessimistic because the architecture is too complex (not really), no documentation (actually one of the best I have seen), training is too hard (I don't agree), the backlog is full of issues (true, but it is standard).

Comment: Are you a team leader or just the  most senior developer in the team ? Be careful not to overstep your bounds . You could mentor few of the brightest if your manager allows it, but focus primarily on your tasks.

Answer (score 13):

This seems fairly straightforward: You believe that your colleagues are whining about a problem that doesn't exist.  This is actionable; they're not whining abut something ephemeral, the problem is very real.  So address it.

Regarding the architecture: Perhaps they think it's complex because they don't understand it.  So you should become the subject matter expert, because you seem to have the best handle on it.  Become the subject matter expert on the architecture, then do a Lunch & Learn presentation to the rest of the team on how it all works, and ELI5 their own system to them.  Once they see that it's not as bad as they think, then maybe they'll become a bit more optimistic.

Regarding the documentation: Just because it's the best you've ever seen, doesn't mean it's good.  Developers are notoriously bad at documentation so if the average is a 1/10 and yours is a 2/10, it's twice as good as the average, but still sucks.  Both things can be true.  That said, perhaps your teammates are not great developers, and even when given very good documentation they don't know how to use it.  Ask your team (or if you overhear in conversations, jump in and help) what their pain points are with the documentation and see what you can do to alleviate it.  Maybe there's too much of it and it's too confusing, so if they have specific questions, point out where they can find the answers quickly and easily.

Regarding training: I don't really know what this means, so I'm going to skip it.

Regarding the backlog: Is the issue that the backlog is too full, or that the backlog fills up faster than it can be emptied?  If you're getting more incoming issues than you can resolve, that's a problem, because it means you'll never catch up and keep falling behind.  If the issue is simply that there's a lot of work to do, perhaps it's the case that you need to implement Scrum better.  If you properly implement Scrum, then you remove the focus from "the backlog", which is a daunting task, and instead focus on "this sprint", which is not.  Let's say you have 1000 tickets, and you can do 10 per week.  Well, if you think about that, it's going to take 2 years to clear up that backlog, that sounds like a lot of work.  But if you only see 10 per week, that seems more doable, on a short-term basis.  So maybe you need better sprint structures and sprint planning.

Failing that, one way to look at the backlog is that, the more work there is to do, the more people are needed to do it.  If the backlog was empty, then the company would probably look to downsize and a bunch of your team would probably get fired.  The fact that the backlog is full means there's work to do, so your job is secure.  Try explaining it like that and it might help :)

Comment: "Regarding training: I don't really know what this means, so I'm going to skip it." -- LOL! ... +1 anyway good answer for the rest

Answer (score 4):

Get your team into a meeting and see what they have to say about fixing the issues they see. Part of being in leadership is listening to your team as well as "laying down the law". The reality is *you* don't have to fix everything. In fact, the more you ask your team about how to fix stuff and use their suggestions, the more buy-in you'll get from the team. This leads directly to higher morale in the team.

In your meeting, have time set aside for all major problems: documentation, code base, backlog, etc. However, don't go right into your own solutions. Ask your team what they think would help. If they don't know, as specific questions about the problem. Some of it can be leading questions, but most of it needs to be open ended so they can come up with their own ideas.

- Is there a specific part of the codebase that's complicated?
- What areas would benefit most from refactoring?
- Where can we improve documentation for ____ app/section/functionality?
- Would peer/pair programming be useful?

Get them to tell you what needs to be done. If you just start in with your own ideas of how to fix things or how you don't think things need fixed, they'll probably just nod and agree, even if that's not how they actually feel or think about it. There's a lot of fear about being argumentative, hard headed, or generally disagreeing with a boss or supervisor, where many employees feel their job is threatened if they are any of those.

Once you get some ideas brought out, see if your team can prioritize them or choose between competing ideas. If this can be done, try to figure out how they can be accomplished, again with input from your team instead of just your ideas.

When you have those solutions brainstormed, take them back to your management for approvals, if necessary. Start getting them into your scheduled tasks and sprint, if that's how you work. Then start working on those solutions. Set up times for the peer/pair programming or 1-on-1 study assistance, or whatever the solutions were.

If you ignore the problems of your team because you don't see the same pain points you do, you won't see any changes in their attitudes. Find out from them what's specifically wrong and work on it. Maybe they don't know the terminology well enough in the training and get confused by it, or it's moving too fast for their skill level. Maybe the documentation is using confusing wording that only makes sense one way, but not another way.

And if all you do is "lead from the front", without listening to anyone, you'll likely just get labeled as a brown-noser, or something similarly derogatory.

This will take time to see changes, so don't think everything is going to turn around "overnight". It might take months and some people will take longer to change than others, with some never being satisfied. This is a work in progress even after things improve. Keep asking asking for improvements and keep working towards those improvements. It can be a very hard battle to turn around a team, but it's easier than dealing with a group of people who are mad and complaining all the time.

Comment: There is no indication that OP is in any kind of leadership position here.

Comment: @Ertai87, "As the dev with the highest level in the team I guess something in that direction is expected from me". I took that to mean it was expected from the management as well as maybe the team itself. If the OP isn't in a leadership position, then the answer would be : No, you can't really do anything to fix the problems. as you don't have the authority to do so.

Comment: I took that to mean that OP sees themself as the one with this highest level of skill, not the highest level of seniority, especially since they are the newest hire on the team.  I could be mistaken though.

Comment: With level I mean "title". There is expectation of some level of leadership and influence in the role, but I'm not formally tech lead or manager. I'm just concerned about the morale in my partition of a cross geo team, and looking for something to do about it.